# How to find if a value matches one of the values from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

FYI: this is for a simple quiz with just a single input field for each answer.

I have the following Javascript if statement to check if the value entered into an input field is correct (in this case, if the value entered is 'england').

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'england') {
        //Stuff
    } else {
        //Other Stuff
    };
});
```

However, I want to allow for alternative spellings, so I need a few possible answers for each question - it seems sensible to use an array for this as so...

```
var ans1 = new Array();
ans1[0] = "England";
ans1[1] = "Englund";
ans1[2] = "Ingland";
```

How can I change my if statement to say 'if the input field value equals any of those values from the array, then do the following'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ans1) > -1) {
    //Stuff
}
```

Here, the code `$.inArray($(this).val(), ans1)` will search for a specified value for example `England` within an array `ans1` and return its index (or -1 if not found).

**UPDATE**

For case-sensitive search:

- First enter all the values in the array in **Lower Case**
- Next use the code below:-

**JS:**

```
if ($.inArray($(this).val().toLowerCase(), ans1) > -1) {
    //Stuff
}
```

Comment: This worked, but only when removing the .toLowerCase() function, which means if users enter the value in capitals then it will not accept the answer. Almost.

Comment: @user2586455: I have updated the answer as you pointed out!

Comment: Excellent! So it was my bad for entering the array values with capitals. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ['indexOf'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of the array, this will return -1 if the value doesn't exist in the array:

```
//if answer is in array
if(array.indexOf(answer) != -1){
    //do stuff
}else{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this makes perfect sense to many, but the answer/code wasn't specific enough for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if(this.value.match(/^(England|Englund|Ingland)$/i))
```

using regex and gi modifier for case insensitive

Comment: `this.value` == `Inglandia` ?

Comment: @thg435 Inglandia? :P

Comment: Exactly! And now 7 more chars so SO will let me post.

Comment: I think thg435's point is that your regex should be `/^(England|Englund|Ingland)$/i`.

Comment: Ah i see now what you mean, and thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: @nnnnnn: `Englundia`? ;]

Comment: @thg435 - Ha, yes, I edited my comment to fix that right before I saw your latest one... (+1 to Anton on the edited version of the answer.)

Comment: The point being that you can do this with a very simple regex; OP can maybe figure the spelling?

Comment: @nnnnnn: damn you're fast, cowboy! Now let's wait for the OP to fix this `length>0` thing...

Comment: there, thanks thg435 and nnnnnn i'm not that great with regex ^^

Comment: Looks fine now, kudos for improving!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$('input').keyup(function () {

var ans1 = new Array();
ans1[0] = "England";
ans1[1] = "Englund";
ans1[2] = "Ingland";
for(int i=0;i<ans1.length;i++)
{

    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() ==ans1[i]) {
        //Stuff
    } else {
        //Other Stuff
    };
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may consider checking each element of the array like that:

```
var ans1 = new Array();
ans1[0] = "England";
ans1[1] = "Englund";
ans1[2] = "Ingland";

$('input').keyup(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < ans1.length; i++) {
       if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == ans1[i]) {
        //Stuff
         } else {
        //Other Stuff
       };
    }
});
```

Not the most beautiful solution, but it should work.

Comment: You could have used hashmap instead or .inArray()

Comment: indeed, but it was already proposed in another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers `$.inArray`:

```
var found = $.inArray('specialword', words) > -1;
```

Note that inArray returns the index of the element found, so 0 indicates the element is the first in the array. -1 indicates the element was not found.

put your spellings in an array like this:

```
words: [
    "England"
    "Inglund"
    "Ingland"
]
```

Found will be true if the word was found.

If you want the index of the matched word delete `> -1` from the line.

Your code would be like this:

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    var found = $.inArray($(this).val(), words);
    found > -1 ? //Stuff : //otherStuff;

});
```